# Link jQuery menu button to url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery menu script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){


            jQuery('#promo').pieMenu({icon : [
                    { 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/winamp.png",
                        alt  : "Winamp",
                        fn   : function(){alert('Click:: Find');return false}
                    },  { 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/vlc.png",
                        alt  : "VLC Media Player",
                        fn   : function(){alert('Click:: Plus');return false}   
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/QuickTime.png",
                        alt  : "Quick Time Player",
                        fn   : function(){alert('Click:: Home');return false}
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/WMP.png",
                        alt  : "Windows Media Player",
                        fn   : function(){alert('Click:: Music');return false}
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/popup.png",
                        alt  : "נגן Popup",
                        fn   : function(){alert('Click: E-Mail');return false}
                    },{ 
                        path : "/wp-content/themes/Tersus/images/piemenu/iTunes.png",
                        alt  : "iTunes",
                        fn   : function(){alert('Click: Config');return false}

            });
        })
    </script>
                        },{
```

I need to link the icons to external URL when clicked, how can i achieve that?

and i'm writing this line because it demands a better code explanation because the code is long...(?)

Comment: can we see the full code (perhaps even a jsfiddle?)

Comment: Yes ofcourse..ill edit in a sec

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){       
   window.location.href = 'http://domain.com/'; 
   return false
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the try..it wont go to url..just this -> http://i48.tinypic.com/dvooyg.png

Comment: remove the alert and see what happens

Comment: It worked...:) it was my fault forgot to add }  thank you very much sir!!

Comment: you think you can help on this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721521/calling-external-plugin-from-inside-another